# Can encoding of miRNAs in introns not cause dysregulation of gene expression?

Tags: molecular-biology, rna-interference

For example, consider a gene X which has an intron which encodes a miRNA that downregulates expression of another gene Y.

When the gene X is translated, this miRNA will appear as a byproduct of splicing, then expression of gene X will inhibit expression of gene Y, which could be deleterious.

How did the mechanisms of gene expression evolve to avoid possible unplanned interference in gene expression?

Comment: Deleterious effects on gene expression are selected against.

Comment: evolution does not think. The ones with any interference would have a disadvantage during selection.

Comment: Agree with the two above comments, selection will select against such a deleterious effects.

Comment: i understand that evolution is not planned, but how enconding of miRNAs in introns could be used as a regulatory mechanism? For example, are there patterns?  miRNA enconded in the intronic sequence of the gene regulating the expression of the same gene, or a related one? Because if miRNAs occured randomly in introns they would not be good regulators.

Comment: I think this might constitute part of the epistatic effects that are being discovered as simple variations turn out to be insufficient in explaining phenotypical differences. So, yes, there must be patterns. There are two recent papers showing that many more miRNAs exist and are expressed in tissue dependent manner. My guess is the patterns will be slowly established by looking into the new intronic miRNAs and their targets.